# Angular - Date Reference Value Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, reference, ionic2

I have a date element like this. It is binded to a date variable called 'FilterOptions.From'. When the value is not current Month, I am coloring in green. This is the element.

```
    <div tappable class="float-left">
       <div (click)="OpenPopupDate($event,0,FilterOptions.From)" [class]="FilterOptions.From.getMonth() == Today.getMonth()?'filter-box':'filter-box color-green'">
            Date From

     <span [class]="FilterOptions.From.getMonth() == Today.getMonth() 
     && FilterOptions.From.getFullYear() == Today.getFullYear() ? 'bold':' bold color-green'">
     {{FilterOptions.From | date : 'MMM yyyy'}}</span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

When you click on the element I set to specific value like this

```
   OpenPopupDate(event, source, date) {

        date.setFullYear(2017);
        date.setMonth(2);

}
```

Now the problem is, I am getting green color and I am seeing correct values in all my queries. However in the view, I am still seeing the old value although the actual value is the updated one.

The problem is I have around 10 Date Elements(FilterOption....) and I don't want to write specific function for each

Comment: This is hard to help you without any code from your component that is in error, or an example of what is happening.

Comment: I am sending FilterOptions.From as Param from html,  then I am updating the year and the month.  It is actually updating but the view is not

Comment: That doesn't provide your component code or an example of what is happening.

Comment: I added a small edit.

Comment: I give up. Good luck.

Comment: I made it simpler. Never give up - Sia

Comment: **Please post the code of your component and an example of what is happening**. I can't be clearer than that.

Answer (score 0):

The object reference does not change, I think. Try this in your component:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Put this line where you want to refresh your view:

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```